# Functionality to start and stop jobs

Tags: jenkins, devops

I am not sure something like Jenkins is built for this functionality, but I am curious if it is possible.

Say I have some sort of code, that I want to run from 7am until 7pm. Typically Jenkins jobs are done when whatever process is complete. Like a python script closing.

my goal would be to be able to have a script that will infinetly run, and will be terminated by Jenkins at a certain time. Doing this would still allow me to see the nice web ui, remotely start it, easily add hooks, etc.

Is this possible in Jenkins, or is there another platform like Jenkins that supports this type of functionality. Basically instead of using Jenkins for 'builds', you would be using them to control services

Answer (score 0):

I have completely replaced Linux Cron with Jenkins, so yeah you can do what you're wanting to do. Only limited by your imagination :)

I have all of my Linux servers configured as nodes (via ssh) within Jenkins, and the connecting account on each of them has sudo privileges, so I can essentially have Jenkins do anything I want it to, at the OS level.

Comment: I've read stuff about issues with long running proceses with jenkins? have you run into that? in my 'dream' implimentation, a process would basically run for 24 hours..and jenkins could be used to stop it/tail its output..

Comment: Can't say that I have had that issue, but I've definitely not run a process for that long. I'd say the longest I've done is about an hour.  Definitely an easy thing to test though. I've been super impressed with the stability of Jenkins, particularly in running remote processes on other nodes.